# regex regarding alternating parts

Tags: regex

I have a log entry and I just want to extract the SQL Statement with a regular expression.
The SQL Statement by be any DDL or DML statement and may have several lines.
The Params section may be missing and the "Got xx Results in xx Ticks" may also be missing. But the ":SQLEnd:" line is always there.
Here are some examples

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = :id and col2= :num ORDER BY ORDERID ASC

Params:
:id -> 60081
:num-> 1

Got 2 Results in 0 Ticks
:SQLEnd:
```

or:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = :id and col2= :num ORDER BY ORDERID ASC

Got 2 Results in 0 Ticks
:SQLEnd:
```

or:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = :id and col2= :num ORDER BY ORDERID ASC

Params:
:id -> 60081
:num-> 1

:SQLEnd:
```

or:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = :id and col2= :num ORDER BY ORDERID ASC

:SQLEnd:
```

Comment: So you want just the first line? What are the valid statements (in terms of the first word)? And which language are you doing this in?

Comment: When you want to parse output (html, plist files, etc...) you need to start looking for tools beyond a standard regex. In this case I would suggest using awk, python or ruby. All of these tools have regular expressions available for string matching and real programming constructs to help with the optional sections.

Comment: not just the first line. I want the whole SQL statement which can be several lines long. this is just an example. I am using C#.net.

Answer (score 0):

A basic regex to match your examples would be:

```
SELECT .+?:SQLEnd:
```

You need to ensure that `.` will match newline characters. In PHP, this would be:

```
/SELECT .+?:SQLEnd:/s
```

However, this regex is not very robust, as it could break when used with certain SQL queries (eg: queries which contain one or more `SELECT` subqueries). And you want to match "any DDL or DML statement", which would be very complex with a regex. As Mark says, it would be better to use a parser rather than a regex.

**Edit**

In C#.net, you would use:

```
new Regex("SELECT .+?:SQLEnd:", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

The documentation for `RegexOptions.Singleline` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx):

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).

You can also use [this inline option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Singleline) to enable single-line mode:

```
new Regex("(?s)SELECT .+?:SQLEnd:");
```

Comment: This does not help me. What I want is regex which remove the EVENTUALLY existing "params" and/or "Got xx Results" part and definitly the ":SQLEnd:" part.

Comment: @EGGFK This regex will match everything between (and including) `SELECT` and `:SQLEnd:`. It will match a multi-line SQL statement, including `Params:` and `Got # Results in # Ticks` and anything else between `SELECT` and `:SQLEnd:`.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Thalman mentioned in the comments you will probably want to research a good parser for this, there are a variety available that should cover any language you should use.

http://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/ (for instance) is a good example of a Python SQL Parser

To answer your question I would use a regular expression:

```
'(s?)(m?)(.*?^:SQLEnd:)'
```

This will match ANY DDL/DML statement but it will do so crudely (explained below).

The flags at the beginning denote DOTALL (dot takes all characters) and MULTILINE ($ and ^ denote the end and start of lines). Most languages will have built in flags that you can activate using whatever regex class they implement. (i.e. Python `re.DOTALL` and `re.MULTILINE` from `import re`.

Please note that this regular expression will only get expressions between instances of ":SQLEnd:" - so

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = :id and col2= :num ORDER BY ORDERID ASC

Params:
:id -> 60081
:num-> 1

Got 2 Results in 0 Ticks
:SQLEnd:
```

will be one group and

```
or:

SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col1 = :id and col2= :num ORDER BY ORDERID ASC

Got 2 Results in 0 Ticks
:SQLEnd:
```

will be another. This is crude (but the only way I can think of to easily account for any DDL/DML statement) but hopefully will work for you. If this is not an option I highly recommend an SQL parser.